# MySQL login Guidance? Spring boot security

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Looking for some guidance on how to implement a login system. So I'm currently using this project: https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/user-account-registration-with-spring-boot for my registration, since it comes with a lot by default. Got everything working fine, so next step is a login system.

But my question is, what does "logging in" actually do to the MySQL db? I get the basic user+pass verification but I'm curious how it knows you are still logged in or how it persistently keeps you as the user you logged into? Wouldn't this be something with cookies?

Regardless, I thought I'd try to implement this example: https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d

This confuses me. Following the code it looks like you do a GET request to /login to see the login page, then on login.html it does a POST request to the /login, but on the controller /login is only set to map get requests? Then somehow SecurityConfiguration.java does something to log you in?

TL;DR: I've been looking around for a while and can't make sense of this? Could someone please explain how logging in works or post some relevant tutorials how spring security works? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The spring samples are always a good place to start.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Although that doesn't include mysql.

You could try DZone they have good tutorials.
e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-4-authenticate-and-authorize-users